# WSO2 ESB Managing feature repository

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I am trying to get available features from wso2 esb 4.5 from the repository http://dist.wso2.org/p2/carbon/releases/4.0.1/

I can see this repository by browing the URL in IExplorer with a proxy configurated. I have add the sample wrapper.conf file to wso2 esb/repository/conf with the following lines

```
wrapper.java.additional.10=-Dhttp.proxyHost=192.168.xx.xx
wrapper.java.additional.11=-Dhttp.proxyPort=8000
```

with no success.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Wrapper mode has been removed since Carbon 4.0.0 which ESB 4.5 is based on. So this will not work.